# mapping from String to a Class type using map<> from STL

Tags: c++

I have a class `Person` which could be of type (an attribute of this class) `EMPLOYEE`, `STUDENT`, `ALUMNI`. In a text file, the 
names (e.g. "John", "Lena", "Mac" etc.) of some Persons are given. The names of persons are in `string` type.

The **text file** looks as following:

```
STUDENT(John)
STUDENT(Victor)
EMPLOYEE(Mary)
ALUMNI(Mac)
```

**Problem:** I want to map the names which are in string type into `Person` type. I need something similar to

```
std::map<string, Person*> person_list;
```

but it is not possible to do so directly.

**I am struck at:**

```
while()
{
    ----
    ----
    string person_name = line.substr( index + 1, ( line.find_first_of(')', index) - index - 1) );
    person_list[person_name] = ?????
}
```

I cannot use `person_list[person_name] = new Person()` because i have to do that in another method given below

```
Person* University::addInput(string name) //Input name was sent as a string from the calling function
{
    Person* new_input = new Person(INPUT, name);
    inputs.push_back(new_input);
    return new_input;
}
```

**Summary:** Whenever i find a person name in my file, i just want to make a new object of type `Person` with an unique id so that i can find it later on.

**PS:** Just a side remark. I want to map from `string` to `Person`because i have an another method which establish a connection between
two persons i.e. `connect(Person* a, Person* b);` but only when certain conditions get fulfilled. So, after mapping all the persons, i need to track them again to connect them based upon some conditions.

Comment: `person_list[person_name] = new Person(...)`? (But please use a smart pointer!)

Comment: `person_list[person_name] = new Person();` perhaps? But I would reccomend to use a smart pointer, instead of the raw `Person*` pointer.

Comment: could you please tell me what is smart pointer...i don't know about it

Comment: @skm - see [What is a smart pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one?rq=1)

Comment: You are almost certainly going to have stale pointers all over the place using this method, or you'll leak memory badly. If you absolutely have to use pointers, use smart pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class `Person`. Are you sure that you must store pointers instead of objects in the `map`? Memory management will be much easier if you let the map own the objects like this:

```
std::map<std::string, Person> person_list;
// while...
Person person; // instantiate an object
person.name = person_name; // you probably want to set some data...
person_list[person_name] = person;
```

Update according to edit...

Ok, the person object in constructed in the `addInput` function and it returns a pointer to the person. If you absolutely must use that, you can do this:

```
std::map<std::string, Person*> person_list;
// while...
Person* person = University::addInput(INPUT(), person_name);
person_list[person_name] = person;
```

Just remember to delete the `Person` objects that were created with `new` before `inputs` is destroyed... or consider storing the objects in that container instead of their pointers. And make sure that `person_list` does not live longer than `inputs`... or use `shared_ptr`

Comment: @skm I cannot see how your update justifies the use of a map of pointers.

Comment: @skm, *why* must you use that function?

Comment: @user2079303: i must have that function because of the set format of the code ...just like that :)

Comment: @skm it doesn't matter. You can still use the function: `connect(&person_list["Alice"], &person_list["Bob"]);`

Comment: @juanchopanza: The problem is, i wont have the names ("Alice", "Bob") to connect. That's why i just need a unique id (something like integer counter)  so that i can connect two persons if certain conditions get fullfilled.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Please read my `PS`...i have elaborated my problem a little more.

Comment: @user2079303: Thanks a lot. At the moment, it is working. If i face any problem then i will start a new theard :)